# Is it OK to use single quotation marks around a business name?

Tags: punctuation

I'm currently in the process of writing a written piece/assignment for university as a contrast and compare piece and was curious as to if using single quotation marks around a business name for example,

> Following the events occurring at a recent convention 'Nintendo Of America' released a new game for the switch.

In the original brief I was given it had referred to the games using single quotes around them. I wonder if the quotes were also necessary for the name of the business. The written format being used throughout is that of an article.

Comment: Why do you think it might not be correct to use single quotes?

Comment: @ColleenV In the original brief I was given it had referred to the games using single quotes around them.

Comment: I’ve edited your question to include the information from your comment. If I didn’t express your thoughts correctly, you should feel free to edit what I have added.

Comment: Welcome to ELL!  Please share what research you have already done, and what you found that confused you.  For example ([1](https://www.englishclub.com/writing/punctuation-quotation-marks.htm)) or ([2](https://w.wiki/8nm)). What do you think the answer might be?  (To improve your question, use the **[Edit]** button on your question and add details, please.)  Please read the "[Contributor's Guide to ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide)" and [Details Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/details-please).  Keep contributing and welcome!

Answer (score 1):

**No. Quotes,single or double, should not be used to indicate a business name.**

Quotes should be used for the following situations:

- When actually quoting someone.

> She said "I am going to be late."

- When indicating the titles of short works or components of works (like chapter titles)

> "The Naming of Cats" is a poem by T.S. Eliot.

- When talking about a word as a word:

> "The" is an example of a definite article in English.

Single quotes to indicate a nickname or similar unofficial short name:

> The address was given by Robert 'Shorty' Johnson

Single quotes to distance yourself from something you report by indicating that you are merely reporting:

> He called his opponent a 'moron'.

Names of businesses can be italicized if you need to distinguish the words from the surrounding sentence.

> Following the events occurring at a recent convention *Nintendo Of America* released a new game.

References: [1](https://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/quotes.asp) [2](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/grammar/dashes-parentheses-and-quotation-marks/uses-of-quotation-marks)

Comment: This isn't what I was asking, I understand how to use quotation marks and that they shouldn't be used when referring to business names what I was asking was about single quotation marks which differ to normal quotation marks.

Comment: And the answer is no, as I said. The above is a list of places youc an use quotes, single or double. Business names are not one.